What is the significance of Jesus' quantifying the period of Israel' s drought in Lk 4:25?
We hear Jesus saying in Lk 4:25 ( KJV)

But I tell you truly, many widows were in Israel in the days of Elijah, when the heaven was shut up three years and six months, and there was a great famine throughout all the land;

We get the previous reference of that in  I Kings 18:1(KJV):

And it came to pass after many days, that the word of the Lord came to Elijah in the third year, saying, Go, shew thyself unto Ahab; and I will send rain upon the earth.

It is implied that it took another six months from God' s direction to Elijah to meet Ahab, for rain to fall. And Jesus quantifies the exact duration of the drought at 3.5 years though it was not specified  as such in OT . What according to Bible scholars, is its significance ?
